# Can manually mount ThunderBay 8 disks but fstab fails

Tags: mount, fstab

I had these configured and working in a mergerfs disk pool, ran into an issue and ended up needing to reinstall Ubuntu server. Since then, I can manually mount the drives in my ThunderBay 8 but the syste doesn't boot after adding them to my fstab.

e.g.

```
# sudo mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/5c3245c8-29a4-416f-b1b4-b49841b81ce2 /mnt/disk1
# lsblk -f
NAME    FSTYPE  FSVER LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sdb
└─sdb1  ext4    1.0         5c3245c8-29a4-416f-b1b4-b49841b81ce2    370.7G    92% /mnt/disk1
```

Add to /etc/ftsab:

```
UUID="5c3245c8-29a4-416f-b1b4-b49841b81ce2" /mnt/disk1   ext4 defaults 0 0

# sudo mount -a
# reboot
```

System will only reboot in emergency mode and suggests looking at journalctl -xb

```
   The job identifier is 20 and the job result is dependency.
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: mnt-disk2.mount: Job mnt-disk2.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-146fef04\x2d22d9\x2d479e\x2db379\x2d3e090bf73fbd.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-146fef04\x2d22d9\x2d479e\x2db379\x2d3e090bf73fbd.device/start failed with r>
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5c3245c8\x2d29a4\x2d416f\x2db1b4\x2db49841b81ce2.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5c3245c8\x2d29a4\x2d416f\x2db1b4\x2db49841b81ce2.device/start timed out.
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/5c3245c8-29a4-416f-b1b4-b49841b81ce2.
   Subject: A start job for unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5c3245c8\x2d29a4\x2d416f\x2db1b4\x2db49841b81ce2.device has failed
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

   A start job for unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5c3245c8\x2d29a4\x2d416f\x2db1b4\x2db49841b81ce2.device has finished with a failure.

   The job identifier is 35 and the job result is timeout.
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /mnt/disk1.
   Subject: A start job for unit mnt-disk1.mount has failed
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

   A start job for unit mnt-disk1.mount has finished with a failure.

   The job identifier is 34 and the job result is dependency.
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: mnt-disk1.mount: Job mnt-disk1.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5c3245c8\x2d29a4\x2d416f\x2db1b4\x2db49841b81ce2.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5c3245c8\x2d29a4\x2d416f\x2db1b4\x2db49841b81ce2.device/start failed with r>
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-905b4733\x2d0ec2\x2d4396\x2d9cbb\x2dc918658f79e9.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-905b4733\x2d0ec2\x2d4396\x2d9cbb\x2dc918658f79e9.device/start timed out.
Jun 04 16:57:21 ghost systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/905b4733-0ec2-4396-9cbb-c918658f79e9.
   Subject: A start job for unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-905b4733\x2d0ec2\x2d4396\x2d9cbb\x2dc918658f79e9.device has failed
   Defined-By: systemd
   Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

   A start job for unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-905b4733\x2d0ec2\x2d4396\x2d9cbb\x2dc918658f79e9.device has finished with a failure.
```

Not sure if it's related, but the Thunderbay has a DisplayPort out and I've seen the "PPM init failed (-110)" error a couple times. Was wondering if maybe it's the driver for that, but searching online doesn't seem to return any results. I only see the PPM error when the fstab entries are active.

Currently I'm at a loss, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer was adding nofail to the fstab entry, i.e.

```
UUID="5c3245c8-29a4-416f-b1b4-b49841b81ce2" /mnt/disk1   ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).